# How to bind model with ng-file-upload, ngf-change not working, file

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

in a previous version i could change the post name of the file field via "fileFormDataName", but now it always sets the post name to "file". I noticed that you changed it with version 7.2.0, but I don't understand how exactly I have to use this key-Map to change "file" to "photo" for example.

Also I used ng-file-changed before to upload a file directly after selection. With the new parameter name "ngf-change" this doesn't work anymore, the function is not being called anymore.

And last but not least: How can I get the dimensions of an uploaded image with my version of your plugin (< 7.2.0)?

I did migrate to the latest version, but it didn't work.... And I don't understand how to reference the file if I bind it to a scope model (via ng-model="messageHistory.commentPhoto"). Do I have to pass it to a scope function like

```
ngf-change="uploadPhoto($file)"
```

or rather

```
ngf-change="uploadPhoto(messageHistory.commentPhoto)"
```

?

Both didn't call the function uploadPhoto() at all. Don't know why.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/huhjo9jm/5/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been able to discern, in versions prior to 7.20 you'd use

```
Upload.upload({
  url: 'some-url',
  file: file,
  fileFormDataName: 'fieldname',
  fileName: 'myFilename.txt'
});
```

In versions >= 7.20 use

```
Upload.upload({
  url: 'some-url',
  data: {{'fieldname,myFilename.txt'}: file}
});
```

Or without a filename, simply

```
Upload.upload({
  url: 'some-url',
  data: {fieldname: file}
});
```